# Play sample file as inline and files from my account as attachment

Tags: products, downloadable, attachment, inline

I am working on the downloadable products.i want my preview file on the frontend should play and customers should able to download the products from their account from my downloadable products.

I know their is one configuration given by magento. Under Sys > Config > catalog > Downladable Information. use content disposition to inline both preview and products from my account will play.

and if i use content disposition as attachement then then preview file and products from my account downlad as attachment

Now actually i want preview to be played (inline) and products from my account should be downladed (attachment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some Debug in the core file i found the solution to my problem and i am sharing my answer.

I had to override function in controller to achieve this task.for this i had created one module which overrides Mage_Downloadable's Download Controller.

Step 1: Create YourPackageName_Downloadable.xml under app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourPackageName_Downloadable>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </YourPackageName_Downloadable>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2. Create config.xml file in app/code/local/YourPackageName/Downloadable/etc/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourPackageName_Downloadable>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourPackageName_Downloadable>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <downloadable>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourpackagename_downloadable before="Mage_Downloadable">YourPackageName_Downloadable</yourpackagename_downloadable>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </downloadable>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create DownloadController.php in app/code/local/YourPackageName/Downloadable/controllers/

```
<?php
    require_once("Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php");
    class YourPackageName_Downloadable_DownloadController extends Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController{

        protected function _processDownload($resource, $resourceType)
        {
            $helper = Mage::helper('downloadable/download');
            /* @var $helper Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download */

            $helper->setResource($resource, $resourceType);

            $fileName       = $helper->getFilename();
            $contentType    = $helper->getContentType();

            $this->getResponse()
                ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
                ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
                ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
                ->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType, true);

            if ($fileSize = $helper->getFilesize()) {
                $this->getResponse()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Length', $fileSize);
            }

            // custom change in core code strats here
            $actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
            if($actionName == "sample"){
                $this->getResponse()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline' . '; filename='.$fileName);
            }else{
                if ($contentDisposition = $helper->getContentDisposition()) {
                $this->getResponse()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', $contentDisposition . '; filename='.$fileName);
                }
            }
            // custom change in core code ends here

            $this->getResponse()
                ->clearBody();
            $this->getResponse()
                ->sendHeaders();

            session_write_close();
            $helper->output();
        }   
    }
?>
```